# Tailwindcss: How to use peer pseudo-class to detect existence of peers?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a generic `input` component that rounds it's corners based on what's around it. Normally this works using the `first:` and `last:` pseudo-classes but there is one case where the label is a peer to the input so it should be fully rounded.

I think what I need to do is identify what the peer element is and then styling according. How can I use the custom `peer` selector to identify if a peer exists in tailwind?

```html
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <label hmtlFor="email" className="peer-[label]">Email</label>
    <input id="email" class="peer-label:only-of-type:rounded-3xl rounded-none bg-green-400" />
  </div>
```

Tailwind Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/PzMukUDQuX 
^ The playground shows what I'm fully trying to do, but for this question, just need to figure out how the custom `peer` syntax is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?
https://play.tailwindcss.com/erZse7TDD4

explanation:

I am not sure peer would work here because:

1. the span is not aways there
2. the label is not a peer of the input it is a peer of the parent container of the input.
3. I used a bunch of complex selectors which works but not sure it is the best solution here. I think you can do something similar via code when you render the items if you are using react.

Edit: improved code and further selector explanation.
One change I would make is  wrapping everything with a div as the last 3 elements had and removing the rounded corners. that gives a generic html like below and we can focus only on the first and last child:

```html
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <!-- label -->
    <div>
      <!-- maybe a span here -->
      <!-- there is aways an input here -->
      <!-- maybe a span here -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

now we can take advantage of something called [arbitrary variant values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants).

now we apply the below selectors directly to the wrapping div:

```js
"[&>*:first-child]:rounded-l-3xl"
// which is apply rounder left (rounded-l-3xl) to any (*) first child (:first-child) directly descendant (>) of myself (&).
```

```js
"[&>*:last-child]:rounded-r-3xl"
// which is apply rounder right (rounded-r-3xl) to any (*) last-child (:last-child) directly descendant (>) of myself (&).
```

the resulting is: https://play.tailwindcss.com/K3vSiUxa4V

EDIT2: without arbitrary values:

similar effect without arbitrary variants:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/Yup53pmaS4

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind pasting some of the code here for reference and commenting what the selectors do? If it works, then this is probably it!

Comment: done. I think the same can be applied in different ways without recurring to arbitrary variants. But depends on how the html is structured. it helps if they all output the same as the last example I pasted.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check for siblings (peers) with `peer-[]` or `peer-[]/name`:

See https://play.tailwindcss.com/Zxj95hjvFP